# v-model depending on conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is a method that returns true or false:

```
canEdit() {
  if (this.$route.params.edit === "edit") {
    return true;
  }
},
```

How do I get the v-model attribute to have the appropriate variable depending on what the canEdit method returns?

```
<b-form-input id="sender" v-model="sender"> </b-form-input>
```

Comment: where `canEdit` is being called?

Comment: @ma_jafari, this method is called in:
methods: {
canEdit() {
  if (this.$route.params.edit === "edit") {
    return true;
  }
}
}

Comment: @hgb123, it doesn't work, error:
'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS  vue/valid-v-model

Comment: you have defined `canEdit` in methods, where did you used it? for example will it be called if a specific action is done(like clicking a button) or in a vue life cycles(like `mounted`)?

Comment: @ma_jafari this is the method I use in mounted () to check if the form is editable.